# Are includes in a .h of a DLL exported? And should they?

Tags: c++, dll, include

I have a huge c++ project in which several different units are built as DLL libraries. Now I have a library that is basic and shall be consumed by most of the other projects.

So lets say the DLL.h file has something like:
`#include <vector>`
`#include "OtherClass.h"`

I added the .lib path etc..., so my other project can use the DLL. In fact I have no errors on including the DLL on my "main" project.

Now my question is the  include is that included in my main project when I do #include "DLL.h"?
My rational being that since I will use vector in almost 100% of the projects that consume this DLL, I might as well push the include to it and not have one in every single project that uses it. (not sure if this is a best or worst practice).
The problem right now is my main project does recognize the types in OtherClass.h but not the type vector. Might this be because I don't explicitly use vector in the DLL and just did the include?

Comment: Header files are NOT exported with the dll. The only stuff that is exported with the dll is the explicitly decorated functions and classes. `#include DLL.h` should chain the dependency to vector.h, so you should be OK (providing you are using the same runtime library), so can you elaborate what "does not recognize vector" is?

Comment: it means that in my main.cpp eventhough I have `#include DLL.h` in my header when I use vector<any> I get an error. Just as it looks when you forget to add the include vector line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the DLL linkage or dependency chaining. The fact is I had forgotten to include the statement:
`using namespace std;`
So when I tried in the main project to do
`vector<int> someVector;`
I got an error that said vector is not a template.
Adding the "using" line solved it.
Another way to solve it would be to use std::vector, but since it is code that is already written, I went with the other options.

Thanks @MadScienceDreams, your question actually led me to the answer! And indeed the includes in the dll are chained to the file using it in this case.